# how to create a mysql table by csv file header?

Tags: mysql, excel, database, csv, batch-file

My goal is to create a MySQL table containing data from my CSV file. 
 is there any way to do this
i don't know whether it is possible or not thorugh csv. the thing is like i want to generate mysql table using csv headers as filed names  i know how to load csv into table which is already created manually but i want to generate table through csv using batch script  and below is my batch script to load csv into table through manually

```
load data local infile "C:\\EQA\\project\\input1.csv" 
    into table request_table 
    character set latin1 
    fields terminated by','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    lines terminated by'\r\n' 
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

here above code is for to load csv into table in which request_table is existing in db.
but i want to load csv into table dynamically?
is that possible?if so can some one help me  out to accomplish this?

Comment: "load csv into table dynamically" - What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: in the sense generate table based on csv headers

Comment: In the CSV is no information about the column data types.

Comment: default varchar as datatype for all fileds! the thing is like every time when i get data in csv file from external source  i have to load it into mysql database if it is for one time i can view the data in csv and create a table manually?if  it is more time that makes me difficult to load the data in mysql like creating table identifying tables and soon

Comment: Then write a script/programm in a language of your choice. I doubt that MySQL can do it for you. It cannot know which defaults are fine for you (length of varchar?).